# X509Certificate rawData

Tags: .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I am working with X509Certificate (.pfx file) for jwt tokens. There is a parameters in the X509Certificate2 called as RawData. I understand that this contains the publicKey for sure and also some other metadata information about the certificate.

I wanted to know whether this rawData parameter contains any other critical information such as the PrivateKey. I am not able to find much documentation explaining these parameters. Can I get more documentation about this parameter, what it contains, and if it is safe to be shared.

Comment: I can't be sure what happens in all cases but in my experiment I created an X509Certificate2 object from a .pfx with a private key. The private key was available in the X509Certificate2 object (HasPrivateKey was true) but RawData did not contain any private key information.

Answer (score 1):

Made an X509Certificate from the RawData of the X509Cetificate having the private key using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor. The new certificate created has HasPrivateKey as false and PrivateKey value as null.

Answer (score 1):

let's say that `X509Certificate certInstance` is an instance of a Pfx certificate with all the goodies.

It depends on the content type when exporting the certificate. You can rebuild the certificate from that raw data. For example,
in C# if I use:

```
certInstance.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
```

Than the private key and public key will be in the raw data.
But if you export as cert or some other value, it can change.
If you export as:

```
certInstance.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
```

It'll strip the certificate of sensitive information such as the private key. However if you use that same raw data and try to convert back to pfx, the private key data will be null.

If you wanted to change the content type of the certificate, you could do something along these lines.

```
byte[] certificateAsBytes = certInstance.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
X509Certificate2 myNewCert = new X509Certificate2(certificateAsBytes);
```

Here's a link to the different content types that are available:

[X509ContentTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx)